# Installng Ubuntu Control Center prompts me with a debconf prompt

Tags: installation, lirc

Since every installation guide uses Ubuntu Control Center and I'm not such an expert with Ubuntu yet, I figured it might be a lot easier to go through any tutorial if I have UCC myself.

So I went to see how to get UCC. I added the PPA in my Software Sources and I used the  Terminal to get and install it UCC.

After installation I get asked something but I don't really get what's being asked here nor what I have to select.
[image: ubuntu control center configuration]

Can anyone tell me what the ./lircd.conf file exactly contains? And also what would be the best option to choose here?

A quick answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a debconf prompt. At some point something you installed asked for [lirc](http://www.lirc.org/), which is used to configure infrared remote controls with Ubuntu.

If you don't have one of these you can safely just select `None` or the model of your remote if you have one via the arrow keys, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to highlight the OK and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue with the process.

Comment: Thanks! Very clear, short and fast answer! All of my appreciation! :)